# hibernate does not create schema on an empty databse

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have the following hibernate.cfg.xml file

[image]

The problem, when I run the migration, the schema is not getting created in the database. I would like to create the schema from scratch. It only generates the script.sql file.

This I the main app file

```
public class DatabaseMigration {


    public static void main(String[] args){

        StandardServiceRegistry ssr = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure("/META-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml").build();
        Metadata meta = new MetadataSources(ssr).getMetadataBuilder().build();

        SchemaExport schemaExport = new SchemaExport();
        schemaExport.setHaltOnError(true);
        schemaExport.setFormat(true);
        schemaExport.setDelimiter(";");
        schemaExport.setOutputFile("db-schema.sql");
        schemaExport.createOnly(EnumSet.of(TargetType.SCRIPT), meta);
}
}
```

Comment: "when I run the migration" - What exactly did you do? What code you ran?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, guys, I have found the mistake.

schemaExport.createOnly(EnumSet.of(TargetType.SCRIPT), meta); was the problem

the target only specifies SCRIPT.

I have replaced it with DATABASE and it works.

Comment: Select this as accepted answer so it shows as solved.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring boot, you can forego the hibernate.cfg file entirely and just go to resources > application.properties file, and move  this line to the file:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

Hibernate should then recreate the schema every time you restart the application.

Comment: I am not using spring - boot. It is a stand-alone app.